# Where is dependency:properties gone?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Old versions of [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) include a [`dependency:properties`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/properties-mojo.html) goal. New versions don't seem to include it. Has it been moved to another plugin, or is it simply deprecated with no chance to access its features (namely having a property for each dependency, allowing as an example activation of profile based upon dependencies) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties-goal is available since version 2.2 (the latest version) of the dependency plugin. Maven 3 uses 2.1 as default, so you have to specify the version of the dependency plugin manually in your pom in the build section.

Comment: The only hard trick was to understand generated property syntax (which in fact is **exactly** the one denoted in plugin goal page ... stupid of me).